# is there any way to get the start time of the thread in gdb core dump

Tags: linux, gdb, coredump

i am trying to find oldest thread in Linux core dump. So i need get start time of each thread that are running. So is there any way to get the start time of thread.

i tried to some command in gdb core file but that gives each call stack of threads but not start time.

Regards
Rabi

Answer (score 0):

> i am trying to find oldest thread in Linux core dump. So i need get start time of each thread that are running.

Your conclusion does not follow from your previous statement.

> So is there any way to get the start time of thread.

No: that time is not recorded anywhere in the thread structure.

However, *in general* Linux allocates thread ids in increasing order, so sorting by thread id should give you the order you desire. For example:

```
(gdb) info thread
  Id   Target Id                           Frame 
* 1    Thread 0x7fa91e769740 (LWP 2128629) __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
  2    Thread 0x7fa91d766700 (LWP 2128632) 0x0000557aa5787165 in fn ()
  3    Thread 0x7fa91af61700 (LWP 2128637) 0x0000557aa5787165 in fn ()
  4    Thread 0x7fa91df67700 (LWP 2128631) 0x0000557aa5787165 in fn ()
  5    Thread 0x7fa91cf65700 (LWP 2128633) 0x0000557aa5787165 in fn ()
  6    Thread 0x7fa91bf63700 (LWP 2128635) 0x0000557aa5787165 in fn ()
  7    Thread 0x7fa91c764700 (LWP 2128634) 0x0000557aa5787165 in fn ()
  8    Thread 0x7fa91a760700 (LWP 2128638) 0x0000557aa5787165 in fn ()
  9    Thread 0x7fa91b762700 (LWP 2128636) 0x0000557aa5787165 in fn ()
  10   Thread 0x7fa919f5f700 (LWP 2128639) 0x0000557aa5787165 in fn ()
```

Here you can see that thread 1 was created first, followed by thread 4, 2, 5, 7, etc (`LWP` is the Linux thread id here).